# why the nav bar collaspe isn't working?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, nav

i'm confused which code i should and which shouldn't. so i just place the site to the dropbox and posting the link here.

http://shaylakarzon.kissr.com/nav/index.html

Please check the navbar. it's responsive but doesn't work when the window is small.

i've messed up something. my navbar working fine when it's single. but it creates a problem when i'm trying to adjust it with my slider. in small device layout it shows the menus when i click the sr-only buttons but the menus don't go back if i cleck the sr-only button again.

code

```
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">toggle Navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>  <!-- container-fluid  -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="navbar-scroll">
              <li class="active"><a href="">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
              <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
          </ul>
            <div class="navbar-right login_poopup">
                <p id="login_poopup"><a>Login<span class="caret"></span> </a></p>     
            </div>
        </div>

    </nav>
```

Comment: Please provide jsfiddle.

Comment: Provide more info. HTML posted by you is corect and works fine .

Comment: check your bootstrap javascript implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

linked up general jquery file link before linked bootstrap css file link
like this.

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
```